# Is there a way to load ajax pages without loading http requests on the requested pages?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http

I've written a javascript/jquery script for a game and my script has the potential to make 100 synchronous page requests. The problem I'm having is the load times are too long. I've diagnosed the cause to be that the pages I'm requesting have several external image links so for each page I request, that page is making ~10 other requests. I don't have a way to remove the images from the pages so is there a way I can just have the ajax request exclude any external http requests?

Here is the portion of my script that makes the request

```
function getPage(i,pages){
    if(i<pages){
        changeHeader(filter_41 + " " + (i+1) + "/" + pages + " <img src='graphic/throbber.gif' height='24' width='24'></img>");
        var urlParams;

        if(urlParam('t') != 0){
            urlParams = {order: $('#orderBy').val(),dir: $('#direction').val(),screen: "am_farm", Farm_page: i, village: urlParam('village'), t: urlParam('t')};
        }
        else{
            urlParams = {order: $('#orderBy').val(),dir: $('#direction').val(),screen: "am_farm", Farm_page: i, village: urlParam('village')};
        }
        ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
            url: "/game.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: urlParams,
            dataType: "text",
            async: true,
            success: function(){
                setTimeout(function(){getPage(i+1, pages);},1);
            }
        });

        ajaxRequest.done(function(data) {
            // append all table rows retrieved from data except for first two and the last
            $('#am_widget_Farm tr', data).not(":last").slice(2).each(function(){
                $('#am_widget_Farm tr:last').after("<tr>"+$(this).html()+"</tr>");
            });
        });
    }
    else{
        setTimeout(function(){
            addTableInfo();
            applyFilters();
            changeHeader(filter_40);
            highlightRows();
        },1);
        $('#am_widget_Farm').show();
        pagesLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to inspect the incoming HTML content and grab whatever pieces out of it that you want, adding only that content to your DOM.  Your browser will not make any requests against resources specified in the incoming HTML until you actually try to add that content to the DOM and render it.

Of course this could be easier said then done depending on how the content you are trying to load is formatted.  If you have control over the pages being loaded, then what you really should do it modify those URL's (or create new URL endpoints) to send only the content you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response Mike. If I understand you correctly, I believe I am already doing that inside ajaxRequest.done(). "Your browser will not make any requests against resources specified in the incoming HTML until you actually try to add that content to the DOM and render it." this helps a lot though. How much would the size of that page matter if all it's requesting is text. I've noticed seconds of difference between page requests with not much more content. Is there a way to only request a specific element rather than the entire page then retrieving that element?

Comment: @ntoombs19 The jQUery `load()` method allows you to specify an element from a remote document that you want to load into the given local DOM element, however this doesn't actually shorten the time taken to fulfill the request on the remote resource, as the entire remote document is still downloaded and the desired element parsed from it.  Really, the only way you can shorten the time it takes to fulfill the actual HTTP response/request is to send less content from the endpoint (i.e. send only the data you need).

Answer (score 0):

The ajax request gets back a string of HTML.  No images are loaded or requested at that time - it's just a string of data.

When you put that string into a jQuery object, jQuery makes it into a DOM fragment by asking the browser to parse it and turn it into DOM objects.  At this point, the browser will parse the `<img>` tags in the HTML and request the `.src` values (causing your problem).

So, to fix your problem, you will need to remove or otherwise disable the `<img>` tags BEFORE the HTML is parsed.  You will probably need to operate on the HTML as a string and you must do this before you give that HTML string to a jQuery object (because that's when it gets parsed and turned into real DOM elements in your code).

I can think of a couple ways to do this:

1. You can create your own crude HTML searcher and remove any `<img ...>` tags from the string of HTML.
2. You can remove any `.src` attributes from the HTML string that are in an `<img>` tag.

If this only has to work with some known content that you can test it with, not any possible content on the web, then you can often take some shortcuts.  For example, here's a simple way to remove `<img>` tags from an HTML string:

```
html = html.replace(/<img[^>]+>/gi, "");
```

Or perhaps a little more foolproof (turn the img tags into something else):

```
html = html.replace(/<img/gi, "<ximg");
```

I'm not saying this is 100% foolproof (a real HTML parser is probably needed for that), but it will probably solve your problem.

Comment: Added code example for finding and removing `<img>` tags from an HTML string.

Comment: Is there some way to use the browser's XML parser for this? Parsing XML should just treat it was uninterpreted DOM fragments, without special treatment of `<img>` tags, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Barmar - I don't know about using the XML parser.